# Linq Grouping with Include

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq, entity-framework

I have the following tables: Items, ItemMovements.

What I would like to get is a list of ItemMovements grouped by ItemID where sum of movement qty per group is greater than 10. Also I would want to link Item too..

Here is what I end up with:

```
    var res = ctx.ItemMovements
            .Include("Item")
            .GroupBy(x => x.ItemID)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: more info please, maybe put some info about `Items` and `ItemMovements`

Comment: where is the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var idQuery = ctx.ItemMovements
    .GroupBy(e => e.ItemID)
    .Select(g => new { ItemID = g.Key, QuantitySum = g.Sum(Quantity) } )
    .Where(e => e.QuantitySum > 10)
    .Select(e => e.ItemID);

var query = ctx.ItemMovements
    .Include("Item")
    .Where(e => idQuery.Contains(e.ItemID));
```

Comment: Thanks! What I was looking for. Small change needed. How to modifys second query to fetch each itemID ONCE only please?

Comment: var query = ctx.Items.Where(e => idQuery.Contains(e.ItemID));